# Truecrypt has marked my C: Drive as a "TrueCrypt Traveler Disk"

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb, encryption, truecrypt

I'm no expert in TrueCrypt or encryption, but I needed to encrypt my USB with a password and it was suggested to me to use TrueCrypt. So after long hours of trying to find out how to add a password, I eventually used another program. Now, after re-booting my computer, it marked my C: Drive as a "TrueCrypt Traveler Disk". Is there any way I can revert this? I haven't made any changes to my main hard drive (that I know of), only to my USB stick. I really want this reverted back. I can provide an image if needed.